# Cascading Changes to Future Entries in a Schedule

Tags: vba

I've been working on a scheduling application and I have the middle tier completed at this point. It's not changed in a few days, so I feel it's ready for review. I have just this one routine that feels dirty. It's definitely verging on arrow code, but without short-circuiting, I'm not sure how it can be improved any farther.

My `Schedule` class wraps a collection of `ScheduleEntries` and provides methods to add entries, remove entries, and cascade changes (as well as a way to listen for changes to the underlying collection). When `CascadeChanges` is called, the collection of entries is searched for dirty records. Those records are then cascaded to  the corresponding records in future Cycles. A number of conditions must be met in order to ensure changes are being cascaded to the correct future entries. Currently, I have sacrificed an amount of performance for cleaner, more readable code. How can this method be improved?

```
Public Sub CascadeChanges()
    Dim innerEntries As SmartScheduleEntries
    Set innerEntries = Me.Entries

    '??? use group id to cascade changes?

    Dim entry As SmartScheduleEntry
    For Each entry In Me.Entries
        If entry.IsDirty Then

            Dim innerEntry As SmartScheduleEntry
            For Each innerEntry In innerEntries

                If innerEntry.Store = entry.Store Then

                    If (innerEntry.Cycle.Year = entry.Cycle.Year _
                        And innerEntry.Cycle.Number > entry.Cycle.Number) _
                    Or innerEntry.Cycle.Year > entry.Cycle.Year Then

                        With innerEntry
                            If .WeekDay = mOldWeekDay And .Week = mOldWeek And .Team = mOldTeam Then
                                .Team = entry.Team
                                .Week = entry.Week
                                .WeekDay = entry.WeekDay
                            End If
                        End With
                    End If

                End If

            Next innerEntry
        End If
    Next entry

    RaiseEvent OnCascadeChanges
End Sub
```

Here are my two test cases. (I've been using [Rubberduck](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/unit-testing-and-todo-lists-in-vba-announcing-rubberduck-version-1-0/) to unit test all of this.)

```
'@TestMethod
Public Sub CascadeShouldUpdateFuture()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

Arrange:
    Dim mock As SmartSchedule
    Set mock = Mocks.MockFullSchedule

    Dim originalDay As VbDayOfWeek
    originalDay = mock.Entries(1).WeekDay

    Dim shouldBeChanged As New SmartScheduleEntries
    Dim entry As SmartScheduleEntry
    For Each entry In mock.Entries
        If entry.WeekDay = originalDay And entry.Store = 6003 Then
            shouldBeChanged.Add entry, entry.ID
        End If
    Next

Act:

    mock.Entries(1).WeekDay = vbFriday ' make a change to first record
    mock.CascadeChanges

Assert:
    For Each entry In shouldBeChanged
        Assert.AreEqual vbFriday, entry.WeekDay, "Cycle: " & entry.Cycle.ToString
    Next

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub CascadeShouldNotUpdatePast()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

Arrange:
    Dim mock As SmartSchedule
    Set mock = Mocks.MockFullSchedule

    Dim originalDay As VbDayOfWeek
    originalDay = mock.Entries(1).WeekDay

    Dim shouldNotBeChanged As New SmartScheduleEntries
    Dim entry As SmartScheduleEntry
    For Each entry In mock.Entries
        If entry.WeekDay <> originalDay And entry.Store <> 6003 Then
            shouldNotBeChanged.Add entry, entry.ID
        End If
    Next

Act:

    mock.Entries(1).WeekDay = vbFriday ' make a change to first record
    mock.CascadeChanges

Assert:
    For Each entry In shouldNotBeChanged
        Assert.AreNotEqual vbFriday, entry.WeekDay, "Cycle: " & entry.Cycle.ToString & "; Store: " & entry.ToString
    Next

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Else
        Resume TestExit
    End If
End Sub
```

For context, below you will find the relevant classes. I'm happy to receive criticism on these, but I'm pretty happy with them as they are.

[image: UML diagram]

**Schedule:**

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mEntries As SmartScheduleEntries

Public Event OnAddEntry(ByRef entry As SmartScheduleEntry)
Public Event OnRemoveEntry(ByRef entry As SmartScheduleEntry)
Public Event OnCascadeChanges()

Private mOldWeek As CycleWeek
Private mOldWeekDay As VbDayOfWeek
Private mOldTeam As String

Public Property Get Entries() As SmartScheduleEntries
    Set Entries = mEntries
End Property

Public Property Set Entries(ByVal value As SmartScheduleEntries)
    Set mEntries = value
End Property

Public Sub AddEntry(ByVal entry As SmartScheduleEntry)
    mEntries.Add entry, entry.ID
    RaiseEvent OnAddEntry(entry)
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveEntry(ByVal entry As SmartScheduleEntry)
    mEntries.Remove entry
    RaiseEvent OnRemoveEntry(entry)
End Sub

Public Sub Validate()
    'todo: implement Validate()
    RaiseNotImplementedError "Validate"
End Sub

Public Sub CascadeChanges()
    Dim innerEntries As SmartScheduleEntries
    Set innerEntries = Me.Entries

    '??? use group id to cascade changes?

    Dim entry As SmartScheduleEntry
    For Each entry In Me.Entries
        If entry.IsDirty Then

            Dim innerEntry As SmartScheduleEntry
            For Each innerEntry In innerEntries

                If innerEntry.Store = entry.Store Then

                    If (innerEntry.Cycle.Year = entry.Cycle.Year _
                        And innerEntry.Cycle.Number > entry.Cycle.Number) _
                    Or innerEntry.Cycle.Year > entry.Cycle.Year Then

                        With innerEntry
                            If .WeekDay = mOldWeekDay And .Week = mOldWeek And .Team = mOldTeam Then
                                .Team = entry.Team
                                .Week = entry.Week
                                .WeekDay = entry.WeekDay
                            End If
                        End With
                    End If

                End If

            Next innerEntry
        End If
    Next entry

    RaiseEvent OnCascadeChanges
End Sub

Public Sub CleanEntries()
    Dim entry As SmartScheduleEntry
    For Each entry In mEntries
        entry.IsDirty = False
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mEntries = New SmartScheduleEntries
End Sub

Private Sub mEntries_Add(ByRef entry As SmartScheduleEntry)
    ' ReRaises event
    RaiseEvent OnAddEntry(entry)
End Sub

Private Sub mEntries_ItemChanged(ByRef outWeek As CycleWeek, ByRef outWeekDay As VbDayOfWeek, ByRef outTeam As String)
    mOldWeekDay = outWeekDay
    mOldWeek = outWeek
    mOldTeam = outTeam
End Sub

Private Sub mEntries_Remove(ByRef entry As SmartScheduleEntry)
    ' ReRaises Event
    RaiseEvent OnRemoveEntry(entry)
End Sub

Private Sub RaiseNotImplementedError(ByVal procName As String)
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, TypeName(Me) & "." & procName, "Not implemented yet."
End Sub
```

**Entry:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum ScheduleEntryError
    ReadOnlyPropertyError = vbObjectError + 3333
End Enum

Public Enum CycleWeek
    weekOne = 1
    WeekTwo
End Enum

Private Type TScheduleEntry
    ID As Long
    GroupID As Long
    Cycle As Cycle
    Team As String
    Store As Integer
    WeekDay As VbDayOfWeek
    Week As CycleWeek
    IsDirty As Boolean
End Type

Private this As TScheduleEntry

Public Event OnWeekDayChange(ByRef outDay As VbDayOfWeek)
Public Event OnWeekChange(ByRef outWeek As CycleWeek)
Public Event OnTeamChange(ByRef outTeam As String)

Public Property Get ID() As Long
    ID = this.ID
End Property

Public Property Let ID(ByVal value As Long)
    If this.ID = 0 Then
        this.ID = value
    Else
        RaiseReadOnlyError "ID"
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get GroupID() As Long
    GroupID = this.GroupID
End Property

Public Property Let GroupID(ByVal value As Long)
    If this.GroupID = 0 Then
        this.GroupID = value
    Else
        RaiseReadOnlyError "GroupID"
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get IsDirty() As Boolean
    IsDirty = this.IsDirty
End Property

Public Property Let IsDirty(ByVal value As Boolean)
    this.IsDirty = value
End Property

Public Property Get Team() As String
    Team = this.Team
End Property

Public Property Let Team(ByVal value As String)
    Dim old As String
    old = this.Team

    this.Team = value
    this.IsDirty = True

    RaiseEvent OnTeamChange(old)
End Property

Public Property Get Store() As Integer
    Store = this.Store
End Property

Public Property Let Store(ByVal value As Integer)
    this.Store = value
    this.IsDirty = True
End Property

Public Property Get Cycle() As Cycle
    Set Cycle = this.Cycle
End Property

Public Property Set Cycle(ByVal value As Cycle)
    Set this.Cycle = value
    this.IsDirty = True
End Property

Public Property Get Week() As CycleWeek
    Week = this.Week
End Property

Public Property Let Week(ByVal value As CycleWeek)
    Dim old As CycleWeek
    old = this.Week

    this.Week = value
    this.IsDirty = True

    RaiseEvent OnWeekChange(old)
End Property

Public Property Get WeekDay() As VbDayOfWeek
    WeekDay = this.WeekDay
End Property

Public Property Let WeekDay(ByVal value As VbDayOfWeek)

    Dim old As VbDayOfWeek
    old = this.WeekDay

    this.WeekDay = value
    this.IsDirty = True

    RaiseEvent OnWeekDayChange(old)
End Property

'read-only property
Public Property Get SetDate() As Date
    Dim result As Date

    ' vbMonday == 2, and our week starts on Monday.
    '   If DayOfWeek == vbMonday, it is the startdate, we should add zero days.
    '   In other words, Add (2 - 2) to startdate if it's Monday.

    If this.Week = weekOne Then
        result = DateAdd("d", this.WeekDay - 2, this.Cycle.StartDate)
    Else
        result = DateAdd("d", this.WeekDay - 2 + 7, this.Cycle.StartDate)
    End If

    SetDate = result
End Property

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = this.Cycle.ToString & "," & this.Team & "," & this.Store & "," & this.Week & "," & this.WeekDay & "," & this.IsDirty
End Function

Private Sub RaiseReadOnlyError(ByVal procName As String)
    Err.Raise ScheduleEntryError.ReadOnlyPropertyError, TypeName(Me) & "." & procName, "Property Is ReadOnly."
End Sub
```

**Entries Collection:**

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "SmartScheduleEntries"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private mCollection As Collection
Private WithEvents mEntryListener As SmartScheduleEntry
Attribute mEntryListener.VB_VarHelpID = -1

Public Event Added(ByRef entry As SmartScheduleEntry)
Public Event Removed(ByRef entry As SmartScheduleEntry)
Public Event ItemChanged(ByRef outWeek As CycleWeek, ByRef outWeekDay As VbDayOfWeek, ByRef outTeam As String)

Public Function Add(ByRef entry As SmartScheduleEntry, ByVal Key As Long)
    mCollection.Add entry, CStr(Key)
    RaiseEvent Added(entry)
End Function

Public Function Remove(ByVal entry As SmartScheduleEntry)

    mCollection.Remove IndexOf(entry)

    RaiseEvent Removed(entry)
End Function

Public Function Item(ByVal index As Variant) As SmartScheduleEntry
Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0

    Set mEntryListener = mCollection(index)
    Set Item = mEntryListener

End Function

Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = mCollection.Count
End Function

' returns index of item if found, returns 0 if not found
Public Function IndexOf(ByVal entry As SmartScheduleEntry) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To mCollection.Count
        If mCollection(i).ID = entry.ID Then
            IndexOf = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = mCollection.[_NewEnum]
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mCollection = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mCollection = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub mEntryListener_OnTeamChange(ByRef outTeam As String)
    RaiseEvent ItemChanged(mEntryListener.Week, mEntryListener.WeekDay, outTeam)
End Sub

Private Sub mEntryListener_OnWeekChange(ByRef outWeek As CycleWeek)
    RaiseEvent ItemChanged(outWeek, mEntryListener.WeekDay, mEntryListener.Team)
End Sub

Private Sub mEntryListener_OnWeekDayChange(ByRef outDay As VbDayOfWeek)
    RaiseEvent ItemChanged(mEntryListener.Week, outDay, mEntryListener.Team)
End Sub
```

**Cycle:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TCycle
    StartDate As Date
    EndDate As Date
    Year As Integer
    Number As Integer
End Type

Private this As TCycle

Public Property Get Year() As Integer
    Year = this.Year
End Property

Public Property Let Year(ByVal value As Integer)
    this.Year = value
End Property

Public Property Get Number() As Integer
    Number = this.Number
End Property

Public Property Let Number(ByVal value As Integer)
    this.Number = value
End Property

Public Property Get StartDate() As Date
    StartDate = DateValue(this.StartDate)
End Property

Public Property Let StartDate(ByVal value As Date)
    this.StartDate = value
End Property

Public Property Get EndDate() As Date
    EndDate = DateValue(this.EndDate)
End Property

Public Property Let EndDate(ByVal value As Date)
    this.EndDate = value
End Property

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = this.Year & "-P" & Format(this.Number, "00")
End Function

Public Sub SetFromString(ByVal value As String)
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Split(value, "-P", 2)
    Me.Year = arr(0)
    Me.Number = arr(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Arrow AntiPattern

Yes your arrow code is dirty it can be broken down into other methods.  They maybe only used in one method now but as your code expands you will find it convenient that these methods are already defined.  I find keeping every method to one or two control structures helps.  Please better names should be used than what I used as I don't fully understand your product.

```
Public Sub CascadeChanges()

    Dim entries As SmartScheduleEntries
    Set entries = Me.Entries

    Dim entry As SmartScheduleEntry
    For Each entry in entries 
        If entry.IsDirty Then CascadeEntry entry, entries
    Next entry

    RaiseEvent OnCascadeChanges

End Sub
Private Sub CascadeEntry(ByVal inputEntry As SmartScheduleEntry, _
        ByVal entries As SmartScheduleEntries)

    Dim entry As SmartScheduleEntry
    For Each entry In entries
        If OughtCascade(inputEntry, entry) And IsOutDated(entry) Then 
            DoCascade inputEntry, entry
        End If
    Next entry 

End Sub
Private Function IsOutDated(ByVal entry As SmartScheduleEntry) As Boolean
    IsOutDated = (entry.WeekDay = mOldWeekDay And _
                  entry.Week = mOldWeek And _
                  entry.Team = mOldTeam)
End Function
```

You might want to abstract various comparisons of `OughtCascade` out but I do know which are relevant enough to abstract.  All of the comparisons are just simple properties, so the lack of short circuit evaluation has marginal cost. Looking back into your Scheduler class, not all of these methods belong in that class.  The following two could be ported to your `SmartScheduleEntry` class.

```
Private Function OughtCascade(ByVal entryFrom SmartScheduleEntry, _
        ByVal entryTo SmartScheduleEntry) As Boolean
    OughtCascade = (entryFrom.Store = entryTo.Store) And _
                   ((entryFrom.Cycle.Year = entryTo.Cycle.Year) And _
                   (entryFrom.Cycle.Number < entryTo.Cycle.Number) Or _
                   (entryFrom.Cycle.Year < entryTo.Cycle.Year))
End Function

Public Sub DoCascade(ByRef entryFrom As SmartScheduleEntry, _
        ByRef entryTo As SmartScheduleEntry

    With entryTo

            .Team = entryFrom.Team
            .Week = entryFrom.Week
            .WeekDay = entryFrom.WeekDay

    End With

End Sub
```

#### `IsDirty` is Dirty

Looking further at your code I am becoming suspicious of the `IsDirty` member.  I believe the property should evaluate whether the entry is dirty or not and not read from a member.  It appears to be causing boiler plate code in the Let properties of other members.

> ```
> Public Property Let WeekDay(ByVal value As VbDayOfWeek)
>
>     Dim old As VbDayOfWeek
>     old = this.WeekDay
>
>     this.WeekDay = value
>     this.IsDirty = True
>
>     RaiseEvent OnWeekDayChange(old)
> End Property
> ```

The issue is `Get IsDirty` is dependent on the code of `Let WeekDay` and other properties.  `Get IsDirty` should be independent on any methods it does not specifically reference.  Isolating `IsDirty` may require completely redesigning your structure.  Seeing as `IsDirty` seems to be synonymous with *HasMutated*, consider making your `SmartScheduleEntry` class immutable.

Comment: That will definitely clean up the arrow code. ++, but I'm not quite grokking what you're trying to say about `IsDirty`. Which boiler plate? `IsDirty` is there so the (yet to be written) data adapter knows which records to save... Dang it. The controller should tell the adapter what to save so it doesn't have to know. Okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I thought you knew better than to use Magic numbers

> ```
> For Each entry In mock.Entries
>     If entry.WeekDay = originalDay And entry.Store = 6003 Then
>         shouldBeChanged.Add entry, entry.ID
>     End If
> Next
> ```

what is so special about store `6003`?

---

What kind of Error is this?

> ```
> Public Enum ScheduleEntryError
>     ReadOnlyPropertyError = vbObjectError + 3333
> End Enum
> ```

A Magic Number Error?

---

I did find this useful to explain the logic here that wouldn't have made sense otherwise.

> ```
> 'read-only property
> Public Property Get SetDate() As Date
>     Dim result As Date
>
>     ' vbMonday == 2, and our week starts on Monday.
>     '   If DayOfWeek == vbMonday, it is the startdate, we should add zero days.
>     '   In other words, Add (2 - 2) to startdate if it's Monday.
>
>     If this.Week = weekOne Then
>         result = DateAdd("d", this.WeekDay - 2, this.Cycle.StartDate)
>     Else
>         result = DateAdd("d", this.WeekDay - 2 + 7, this.Cycle.StartDate)
>     End If
>
>     SetDate = result
> End Property
> ```

---

Code looks Pretty, for VB anyway.

Comment: I'll accept guilt on the first magic number. I should have defined an `expectedStoreNumber` constant, but the second one you pointed out is the constant assignment. What kind of error is it? It's a `ReadOnlyProperty` error. Says so right there. =;)-